# Interface extending TimerTask

Tags: java, timer, interface, timertask

I'm working on getting my interface to extend TimerTask in Java. But my code will give the next error: "Interface expected here" at the declaration of the interface.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public interface IEffectenBeurs extends TimerTask {

   public List<IFonds> getInfo();

   public void run();

}
```

Comment: `TimerTask` is a class. Interfaces can only extend other interfaces.

Comment: You should consider using a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of a `Timer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimerTask is an abstract class. Therefore an interface can't extend it. Your IEffectendBeurs could either extend Runnable or you could transform it to an abstract class too.